# React parent-child communication: TypeError: _this.state.myFunction is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, runtime-error, frontend

I'm new to the world of React and I'm trying to build a parent component with a function that should be invoked from a child component. However, when I call the function, I get the error message in the title. I have something similar:

```html
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

  myFunction(param) {
    //do something  
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <ChildComponent event={this.myFunction} />
    );
  }
 }
 
 
 class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inheritedFunction: this.props.event
    };
  }
  
  childFunction(param) {
    //do a few things first
    this.state.inheritedFunction(param);
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
     <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.childFunction.bind(this)></input>
    );
  }  
 }
```

My code compiles and runs, and then when it gets to execute the childFunction( ) upon selecting the checkbox, this.state.inheritedFunction(param) says that it is not a function and the application collapses. I suspect that it has to do something with binding, but I'm really not sure and stuck with this problem.

I'm new to React, so please be nice. :-) Anyone knows what I messed up?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

  myFunction = (param) => {
    //do something  
    alert(param);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ChildComponent event={this.myFunction} />
    );
  }
 }


 class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inheritedFunction: this.props.event
    };
  }

  childFunction(param) {
    //do a few things first
    this.props.event(param);
  }

  render(){
    return(
     <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.childFunction.bind(this)></input>
    );
  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is trying to save a reference inside the state and then on the onchange callback you are binding again the function.

remove the `state` on the constructor and just call it directly from `props`

```html
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFunction = this.myFunction.bind(this);
  }

  myFunction(param) {
    //do something  
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <ChildComponent event={this.myFunction} />
    );
  }
 }
 
 
 class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.childFunction = this.childFunction.bind(this); // bind on the constructor.
  }
  
  childFunction() {
    //do a few things first
    this.props.event(this) //call the prop directly here.
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
     <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.childFunction></input> // no more binding here
    );
  }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  myFunction = param => {
    //do something
  };

  render() {
    return <ChildComponent event={this.myFunction} />;
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  childFunction = (param) => {
    //do a few things first
    this.props.event(param);
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.childFunction} />
  }
}
```

Comment: Or if you just need to invoke that function, you can direct use this code 
<input type='checkbox' onChange={this.props.event}/>